# c++ list isn't working

Tags: c++, list, iterator, infinite

I think the problem is because of jt iterator when I erase an element from my list, I don't know exactly why but I'm pretty sure that v.end() is changing and my iterators are jumping over it. By the way, I'm sorting the list in descending order.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("barci.in");
ofstream fout("barci.out");

int n,x,i,g,dif,ng,nd,k;

list <int> v;
list <int>::iterator it,jt;

bool cmp(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b;
}

int main()
{
    fin>>n>>g>>dif;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fin>>x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    v.sort(cmp);

    /*for(it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); it++)
        fout<<*it<<" ";*/

    for(it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); )
    {
        ng=g-*it;
        nd=*it-dif;

        for(jt=++it; jt!=v.end(); jt++)
            if(*jt<=ng && *jt>=nd)
            {
                jt=v.erase(jt);
                break;
            }

        k++;
    }

    fout<<k;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do not use [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). And you can avoid the problem to erase manually?

Comment: Consider providing a [MCVE]. Your example requires specific files and we can't guess what they contain. If we could try your code ourselves, it would make it much easier to identify the problem. Using significant names can also help understand and reason about your code.

Comment: barci.in 8 100 10
81 37 32 88 55 93 45 72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you erase an element when `jt` == `it` (the first round in the loop), `it` will be invalidated and cannot be incremented.

Then `jt=++it` does something bad on the next iteration.

Comment: And how can I fix it ?

Comment: I don't know really. You are confusing everyone with the `break` after the `erase`. I haven't seen that before. That seems to restart the scan from an earlier point. Is that really needed? Otherwise the standard incantation is to have an `else ++jt;` after the if and remove the increment from the for-loop header.